# Electrical Drawing Question

Tags: power, wire, drawing

[image]I was looking at the electrical drawing above - for US commercial construction.

Could you please explain what the following lines mean?

4#250, 1#4 GRD. 2-1/2" C

or

3-#8 +10 GRD in 3/4" C

Comment: Cable specification? I'm not familiar with US nomenclature, but I'm sure someone will chip in here. 4 conductors of 250 circular mils + AWG 4 ground shield?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 4#250, 1#4 GRD. 2-1/2" C

4 wires of building size 250 MCM, and one ground wire of #4 AWG in a 2-1/2" conduit.

> 3-#8 +10 GRD in 3/4" C

3 wires of #8 and a ground wire (probably meant #10 AWG) in a 3/4" conduit.